# git hook to set username and email

Tags: git, githooks

Is it possible to write a git hook that sets the username and email before the first commit? The username and email should be set depending on configured parameters like repository / domain regex or other ones.

I tried to write different types, but I only succeeded in that the configuration change *after* the first commit.

**Edit**

My code looks like this (based on [Create a global git commit hook](https://coderwall.com/p/jp7d5q/create-a-global-git-commit-hook)):

```
.git-templates/hooks/ -> cat pre-commit 
#!/bin/bash
remote=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
if [ -n "$remote" ]; then
    if [[ $remote =~ "specific_domain" ]]; then
        git config user.email "myname@specific_domain.tld"
        git config user.name "Firstname Lastname"
    else
        git config user.email "pseudonym@general_domain.tld"
        git config user.name "pseudonym"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Which hooks have you tried? Could you share some of your code? Have you tried `pre-commit`?

Comment: have you read this https://www.raphael-brugier.com/blog/git-verify-email-hook/ ?

Comment: @shreyasminocha Added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git has already set up all the information by the time it runs your pre-commit hook.  You can observe this by writing this always-fail pre-commit hook:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

echo pre-commit hook run
env | grep GIT
exit 1
```

Observe that `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, and `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` are already set.  These are the values that will go into the commit.  As they are environment variables, any changes you make in the hook will have no effect on the parent Git process, either.

What you *can* do is write a pre-commit hook that *checks whether the name ane email address are set correctly*.  If they are not, it can either update them immediately and exit 1, or print a reminder to configure them (along with the actual `git config` commands, suitable for cut-and-paste) and exit 1.  This is not perfect but will handle many use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alias solution for the problem

```
# Git
# gcw
# sets local username + email in repo
# Usage: gcw git-repo-to-clone
git_clone_wrapper () {
    first_arg = "$ 1"
    if [$ # -ne 1]
    then
        echo "only works with one argument (repo)"
        exit
    fi
    git clone "$ first_arg"
    python - << EOF
import os
from urlparse import urlparse
result = urlparse ("$ first_arg")
git_repo_full = result.path.rpartition ('/') [2] # get last element
git_repo_dir = git_repo_full.split ('.') [0]
os.chdir (os.getcwd () + '/' + git_repo_dir)
os.system ('git config --local user.name "Firstname Lastname"')
os.system ('git config --local user.email "myname@specific_domain.tld"')
EOF
}
alias gcw = 'git_clone_wrapper'
```

You can use `gcw` for your private stuff and global git config using `git clone` for your public.

I wrote a little article about it [here](https://secf00tprint.github.io/blog/git/config/en)